# MS ASM 8086 Comparison and Conditional Jumping

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

What the conditional jumping is checking before jump to the label in this 
example :

```
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, 1
repeatAgain:
    add eax, ecx
    cmp ecx, 3
    inc ecx
    jle repeatAgain

    nop
    ret
```

And what the conditional jumping is checking in this example (Where is checking for the equality before proceeding with the jumping ?):

```
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, 1
repeatAgain:
    add eax, ecx
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, 3
    jle repeatAgain

    nop
    ret
```

I explained a little bit confusing but I hope you got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Jxx` commands check the bitstate of a special register which is called "flags". Many instructions do change the state of this register indirectly. So an `Jxx` command effectively takes branch depending on the result of a **last** such instruction.

Thus the order matters here: `inc ecx / jle repeatAgain` does branching if (and only if) ecx <= 0 after the increment (i.e. about 2 billions of iterations, until ecx is overflowed in the highest/sign bit). While `cmp ecx, 3 / jle repeatAgain` does branching only if ecx <= 3 (i.e. 3 iterations only).

> Where is checking for the equality before proceeding with the jumping ?

Well, it's `cmp ecx, 3` (which effectively sets up the "flags" state, as if you've calculated the expression `ecx - 3`, i.e. is `ecx - 3` less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero?), but in fact the loop is broken by the "greater" condition. I.e. the backward branch will not be taken only when ecx becomes 4.

Comment: So when I do the increment then the conditional jump is comparing the value in the ecx flag with the value in the sign flag before proceeding right ?

Comment: @KaldataUser When you do the increment, the flags register changes. The conditional jump itself does not need to compare anything. It uses the current state, i.e. "**jle**" means "**j**ump if the result of the last operation was **l**ess or **e**qual to zero".

Comment: @KaldataUser The `JLE` is testing `ZF = 1 or SF <> OF`. "flags" are separate register (`pushf/popf/lahf` can be used to access it directly as value, or any of the `SETcc/Jcc` variant to test for particular flags (bits) set/unset). The `INC` does affect all flags in the same way as `add x,1` except CF (!), and `DEC` is same as `sub x,1` except CF again (that preservation of CF is speciality of `inc/dec`). As `JLE` is not CF-sensitive, no relevant flag results from `cmp` will survive the `inc`. (if there would be `JBE` (CF=1 or ZF=1), then the jump would use mix from the two `cmp+inc`).

Answer (score 0):

The first conditional jump is following an `inc` instruction:

```
inc ecx
jle repeatAgain
```

The second one is just after a `cmp` instruction:

```
cmp ecx, 3
jle repeatAgain
```

The *conditional code* is the same in both *conditional jumps*: `le`, which stands for *less or equal*.

The jump will be then performed in the first case if the result of the increment-by-one operation (`inc`) is non-positive and in the second case if `ecx` is lower or equal than `3`.